# Split a string in java using regex

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to split a string using a regex "A.*B", which works just fine to retrieve strings between 'A' and 'B'. But the dot '.' doesn't include new line characters \n,\r. 
Can you please guide me on how to achieve this?

Thanks

---

Thanks all. Pattern.DOTALL worked like a charm.

I had another question related to this. What should be done if I need to extract all the strings between 'A' and 'B' (which basically match the above regex).

I tried using find() and group() of matcher class, but with the pattern below it seems to return the whole string.

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("A.*B",Pattern.DOTALL);`

Comment: does `A[.\n\r]*B` work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(String regex, int flags), esp. the DOTALL flag

Answer (score 1):

Use a java.util.regex.Pattern with the MULTILINE flag:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("A.*B", Pattern.MULTILINE);
pattern.split(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try "A[.\\s]*B"

Or you may specify the DOTALL switch so that "." will include even line terminators. Take a look ať the documentation of the Pattern class.

Answer (score 1):

Compile the regex with this option: `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("A.*B",Pattern.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the `Pattern`, `Matcher` classes for this.

Have you tried providing `MULTILINE` to your `Pattern.compile()` method?

`Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE)`

> '.' = Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt

Answer (score 0):

Try changing yor regex to `"A(.|\\s)*B"` This means `A followed by any character(.) or any white character(\s) any number of times followed by B` (double scaped \s is needed at java Code).

Reference for Regular Expressions (constructs, spacial characters, etc.) in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html